# maintain Java serialization compatibility when changing type of a single final field

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

I have this old convenience class for manipulating dates (yyyy-MM-dd). It abstracts away some ugliness of using `java.util.Date` and `Calendar` but I want to rewrite it in terms of JodaTime `LocalDate`. (I won't be changing the interface, just implementation for now.)

The old version used default serialization, and had only the one `int` field.

**How can I replace the `final int` field with a `final LocalDate` but retain serialization compatibility?**

I can implement `writeObject` to write out the compatible `int` value instead of the `LocalDate`. But I don't believe `readObject` or `readResolve` allow me to read the `int` from the stream and write the `LocalDate`, without resorting to reflection.

Is there anything like a static `readInstantiate` method? Or a clever way of doing this with serialization proxies, still maintaining compatibility?

---

The current code:

```
public final class MyDay implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 12345L;

  private final int isoDate;

  public MyDay(int isoDate) {
    this.isoDate = isoDate;
  }

  // lots of convenience methods for manipulating dates

  // no read/writeObject serialization methods in original
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're probably looking for the [readResolve()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/input.html#5903) method:

> For Serializable and Externalizable classes, the readResolve method allows a class to replace/resolve the object read from the stream before it is returned to the caller. By implementing the readResolve method, a class can directly control the types and instances of its own instances being deserialized. The method is defined as follows:

```
ANY-ACCESS-MODIFIER Object readResolve()
        throws ObjectStreamException;
```

So, you need to make the LocalDate field transient, and to use the readResolve class to read transform the read serialized object, containing only the int field, to a new instance containing a LocalDate created from the int value.

Comment: So I'd need to keep the `int` field there. That would work, but it's a (small) shame to require the extra field.

Comment: no you do not need to keep the int field. Just need to be ready to read and ignore it. Can try it with the old and new version serialized. and then use the old versions serialized form to be read in to the new. @joe-kearney

Comment: But `readResolve` isn't given the stream, so you can't read the value of the `int` from there. Default serialization obviously won't write the int anywhere sensible, so where you get the value with which to initialise the LocalDate?